# datagridview display selected row from sql database?

Tags: c#, database

i'm c# programmer. At present, i am try to add some 3 of 5 columns (fileId, filePath, authorName, fileContent, DateSend) in sql data in the datagrid-viewer ; the fileId and fileContent column are hidden. Thank you very much!

```
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LEO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = datashare;Integrated Security = True");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from maintable", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlRead;
        try
        {
            sqlRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlRead.Read())
            {
               //Adding to datagrid
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: If you are a beginner you might check the SQLDataSource control out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To hide the 2 fields create a OnRowCreated event in the grid:

> OnRowCreated="gridView1_RowCreated"

Remember to populate the grid using the

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();     
gridView1.DataSource = reader;
```

and the gridview must have property must be `AutoGeneretedColumns = "true"`

Then create the event as follow:

```
protected void gridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataControlFieldCell cell =
                        (DataControlFieldCell) e.Row.Cells[i];


                    if (cell.ContainingField.HeaderText == "fileId")
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                        cell.Visible = false;
                    }

                    if (cell.ContainingField.HeaderText == "fileContent")
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                        cell.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataControlFieldCell cell =
                        (DataControlFieldCell) e.Row.Cells[i];

                    if (cell.ContainingField.ToString() == "fileId")
                    {
                        cell.Visible = false;
                    }

                    if (cell.ContainingField.ToString() == "fileContent")
                    {
                        cell.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

This might not be the most effecient way but it serve the purpose using code. One should be able to hide the columns using the gridview template when the columns are bound.